# Finding Unions and intersections given two probabilities.

Tags: probability

I am currently trying to find the unions and probabilities given:

`A = .2` and `B = .6`. P($A\cap B$) = .12

And am looking to find the following:

P($A^c\cap B$) For this I just did $.8*.6$ which gives .48.

P($A\cup B$) Here I apply P(A) + P(B) - P($A\cap B$) -> (.2+.6)-(.12) = .68

P($(A\cup B)^c$) Here I just give the opposite of the previous answer -> .32

Did I approach these probabilities correctly? I was unsure of the formulas to use in order to solve these probabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is in this case equal to $\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$, the events $A$ and $B$ are **independent**, so the answer you got is correct.

However, you would not necessarily be viewed as having written a correct solution. If for example $\Pr(A\cap B)=0.1$, multiplying $0.8$ by $0.6$ would yield the wrong answer.

I suggest using an argument like this. We have
$$\Pr(A^c\cap B)+\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(B).$$
We know two of the terms, so we can find the third, which is $0.6-0.12$.

Your other two arguments are correct.

Comment: That makes sense to me! My only question left is for the unions, do I always use that equation to find it?

Comment: I indicated that you are right about $\Pr(A\cup B)$. The (important) equation you used is the best approach if you already know $\Pr(A)$, $\Pr(B)$, and $\Pr(A\cap B)$. Other pieces of knowledge might require a different approach.

Comment: Okay awesome. For instance though, If given the problem $P(A^c \cup B)$ would I do $P(A^c)$ + P(B) - $P(A^c \cap B)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. From the earlier calculation, we know $\Pr(A^c\cap B)$, so the method you suggest will work. Other ideas might be suggested by drawing a Venn diagram. That's always useful, it grounds the intuition.